# Number of row not shown in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

I have this table view in which I display some data on 3 columns. I know that each row should automatically be numbered by the table like:

_ column_1 column_2 column_3

1  data_1  data_2 data_3

2 data_1 data_2 data_3

.....

My problem is that the row number doesn't appear. Is there some function that I have to enable?

I tried

table.verticalHeader.show();

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I re-implemented the headerData function for my table view and somehow there was a conflict between the row numbers and the column headers and the row numbers got obscured. I commented the function and now the row numbers appear.

Comment: What if we want to use the reimplementation of the headerData method?

Comment: can we see what you did? i have exact problem

Comment: nvm. I got mine answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020644/adding-row-number-to-qtableview-in-pyside2. same problem. using pyside2